# Interpreting GCC vectorization report

Tags: c++, gcc, vectorization

I am trying to vectorize some C++ code, but GCC 4.8.4 will not do it.

I am using flags `-mavx -O3 -felide-constructors -funroll-loops -fstrict-aliasing -Wdisabled-optimization`. Also tried with `-O2 -ftree-vectorize` instead of `-O3` but same results.

Here is the output from `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=7`:

```
Analyzing loop at test.C:373

test.C:373: note: ===== analyze_loop_nest =====
test.C:373: note: === vect_analyze_loop_form ===
test.C:373: note: === get_loop_niters ===
test.C:373: note: ==> get_loop_niters:(unsigned int) prephitmp_2594
test.C:373: note: Symbolic number of iterations is (unsigned int) prephitmp_2594
test.C:373: note: === vect_analyze_data_refs ===

test.C:373: note: get vectype with 4 units of type const value_type
test.C:373: note: vectype: const vector(4) double
test.C:373: note: get vectype with 4 units of type const double
test.C:373: note: vectype: const vector(4) double
test.C:373: note: get vectype with 4 units of type const double
test.C:373: note: vectype: const vector(4) double
test.C:373: note: get vectype with 4 units of type const double
test.C:373: note: vectype: const vector(4) double
test.C:373: note: get vectype with 4 units of type const double
test.C:373: note: vectype: const vector(4) double
test.C:373: note: get vectype with 4 units of type const double
test.C:373: note: vectype: const vector(4) double
test.C:373: note: get vectype with 4 units of type const double
test.C:373: note: vectype: const vector(4) double
test.C:373: note: get vectype with 4 units of type double
test.C:373: note: vectype: vector(4) double
test.C:373: note: not vectorized: not suitable for gather load _199 = MEM[(double &)_407];

test.C:373: note: bad data references.
test.C:373: note: ***** Re-trying analysis with vector size 16

test.C:373: note: === vect_analyze_loop_form ===
test.C:373: note: === get_loop_niters ===
test.C:373: note: ==> get_loop_niters:(unsigned int) prephitmp_2594
test.C:373: note: Symbolic number of iterations is (unsigned int) prephitmp_2594
test.C:373: note: === vect_analyze_data_refs ===

test.C:373: note: get vectype with 2 units of type const value_type
test.C:373: note: vectype: const vector(2) double
test.C:373: note: get vectype with 2 units of type const double
test.C:373: note: vectype: const vector(2) double
test.C:373: note: get vectype with 2 units of type const double
test.C:373: note: vectype: const vector(2) double
test.C:373: note: get vectype with 2 units of type const double
test.C:373: note: vectype: const vector(2) double
test.C:373: note: get vectype with 2 units of type const double
test.C:373: note: vectype: const vector(2) double
test.C:373: note: get vectype with 2 units of type const double
test.C:373: note: vectype: const vector(2) double
test.C:373: note: get vectype with 2 units of type const double
test.C:373: note: vectype: const vector(2) double
test.C:373: note: get vectype with 2 units of type double
test.C:373: note: vectype: vector(2) double
test.C:373: note: not vectorized: not suitable for gather load _199 = MEM[(double &)_407];

test.C:373: note: bad data references.
```

What does "not suitable for gather load" mean? Also, what do all the "get vectype" and "vectype" mean?

The loop accesses data from an `std::vector<>`, and it accesses the elements in order from beginning to end.  I see no reason why this should not vectorize, and I can't figure out what GCC is trying to tell me.

I know I haven't given the actual code itself, so I don't expect any help fixing it. I just want to know how to parse GCC's output.

**Update**

Intel will vectorize this loop without the use of pragmas

**Update 2**
The basic idea of my code is that I have a 2D c-style array that I loop over and do some basic arithmetic using the stored values. I wrote a class that uses a 1D c-style array as the base data structure, and overloads the `[][]` operators to mimic the same functionality. The 1D array stores data in the proper stride so that iterating over the 2D version in proper c-style will yield the same iteration in the 1D. I have personally verified the accuracy of the data storage using a small data set, so the functionality and underlying storage are correct and should vectorize. I don't understand why it doesn't, and I need help decoding GCC's output

Comment: I think it would help quite a bit to see the code that you are compiling....

Comment: I realize that may be helpful, but the code I'm working on is part of a larger project, and the relevant parts are several hundred lines. I can't come up with an adequate code snippet that reproduces the same problem...

Comment: As usual, [create an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It shouldn't be too hard to come up with a simple free-standing function that contains a loop which is a good candidate for vectorization. Reasoning about an isolated example will also be easier for you than having your whole large project in mind. And if you're unable to reproduce the results with a small example, you can be confident that there must be something else in your project that has unexpected effects.

Comment: does intel have any major differences in fundamental data type sizes? could `-m64` help here? I'm probably way wrong here, just curious.

Comment: Unless you expect someone who writes vectorization code for GCC to catch this (and I have seen GCC experts here, but I also don't think it's their "main haunt"), code would help a whole lot to understand what the compiler is doing [and more importantly, what changes may be needed "fix" the problem]

Comment: First thing I would try is check if more recent versions of gcc do a better job. Essentially, gcc had trouble noticing that the memory accesses are as regular as you say they are. You could use `-fdump-tree-all` and look at the dump just before vect to see what the vectorizer is being fed, and try to guess what is confusing about it.

Comment: I've voted to close because, with no MWE after 2 years and multiple new versions of GCC, it's unlikely this question will ever get a satisfactory answer.